# Relation connecting $(3n)!$, $3^n$ and $n!$

Tags: combinations, factorial, gamma-function

Any idea on the relation for $(3n)!$ in terms of $3^n$ and $n!$ ?
I have seen that there exist such relation for $(2n)!$ in terms of double factorials, ie.
\begin{equation}
(2n-1)!!= \frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}. 
\end{equation}

Comment: Triple factorial on both $3n-1$ and $3n-2$?

Comment: Um... what's your question?

Comment: Can you show the proof of $(2n)!$ relation. I believe it will show you the same step.

Comment: Okay $!!$ means the product of the odd values.  We'd need to invent a notation of $!!!$ being the product of all $n\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ *AND* we'd need to invent a notation of $!!!_2$ being the producto of all $n\equiv 2 \pmod 3$ and we could say $(3n-1)!!!(3n-2)!!!_2 = \frac {(3n)!}{3^nn!}$.

Comment: Oops.  I forgot what $!!$ actually means.  If $n!!$ is to product of all values with the same parity as $n$ then we can define $!!!$ and the product of all values with the same equivalence $\pmod 3$.  So $(3n-1)!!!(3n-2)!!! = \frac {(3n)!}{3^nn!}$.

Comment: In general, $$\frac{(mn)!}{m^nn!}=\prod_{k=1, m\not\mid k}^{mn} k.$$ Whether you invent a notation for this, or something like it, is up to you, but I don’t think there is a standard notation.

Comment: You can write it in terms of the $\Gamma$ function. Something like $$3^{2n}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/3)\Gamma(\Gamma(n+2/3)}{\Gamma(1/3)\Gamma(2/3)}$$

Comment: Basically, $$(2n-1)!!=2^n\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(1/2)}$$$

Answer (score 1):

Just duplicate the exact same idea.

$(3n)! = 1\cdot 2 \cdot ....... \dot 3n = $

$(3\cdot 6 \cdot ...... \cdot 3n)\times (4\cdot 7 \cdot ....... \cdot (3n-2)) \times (5\cdot 8\cdot..... \cdot (3n-1))=$

$3^n\times(1\cdot 2 \cdot ..... \cdot n) \times (3n-2)!!! (3n-1)!!!$

$3^n\cdot n!\cdot (3n-2)!!!\cdot (3n-1)!!!$

where $K\underbrace{!!!....!}_{m}$ is defined to be the product of natural numbers up to $K$ that have the same remainder as $K$ does when divided by $m$ (or in math jargon-- the product of all natural numbers less than or equal to $K$ that are in the same equivalence class modulo $m$ as $K$).

So $(3n-1)!!!(3n-2)!!! = \frac {(3n)!}{3^n\cdot n!}$

.....

Take it further:

$(kn)! = k^n\cdot n!\times (k(n-1) + 1)\underbrace{!!!...!}_k\times (k(n-1) + 1)\underbrace{!!!...!}_k.... \times (kn- 1)\underbrace{!!!...!}_k$

or

$(k(n-1) + 1)\underbrace{!!!...!}_k\times (k(n-1) + 1)\underbrace{!!!...!}_k.... \times (kn- 1)\underbrace{!!!...!}_k =\frac {(nk)!}{k^n\cdot n!}$.

====

Thomas Andrews points out that we although $!!$ may (or may not?) be standard for $n!! = \prod_{m:m\equiv n\pmod 2;m\le n}m$, that $\underbrace{!!!...!}_k$ meaning $n\underbrace{!!!...!}_k=\prod_{m: m\equiv n\pmod k; n\le n}m$ is probably not.

I could write my final result, as he suggested in the comments, as:

$\frac {(kn)!}{k^n\cdot n!} = \prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(\prod_{m:m\equiv j\pmod k,m\le n} m)$

(Not sure that's a very useful result but....)

Comment: There's an $n!$ in there somewhere right? ($\prod_{k=1}^n 3k=3^n n!$.)

Comment: Dango!! typo/ommision/farts!

Comment: Just make clear you are inventing notation, not that this is any standard.

Comment: I'm not sure what is or isn't standard.  Is $!!$ standard?  Is $!!!$?  It strikes me if $!!$ is standard than $!!!!......!$ ought to be (although it is ugly and unyeildy.  I'll edit my post to take the into account.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews [Wolfram begs to differ.](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multifactorial.html)

Comment: Standards, schmanders......